# Compile error unqualified-id before

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I have

```
class Node
{
public:

string el1;
string el2;
string curr;
string name;
int ID1;
int ID2;

Node(){
//constructor is here
ID1=-1;
ID2=-1;
}

};
```

And it has 10 different nodes represented with array..

```
Node [] allNode=new Node[10];

for(i=0; i< 10; i++)
{
//create new node
allNode[i] = new Node();

std::string el = "f";
std::string el2 = "g";
std::string allNode[i].curr;

allNode[i].curr = name + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(i);
cout << "Node name " << allNode[i].curr <<endl;

}
```

However, I have compile error as below:-

```
error: expected unqualified-id before ‘[’ token referring to Node [] allNode=new Node[10];
error: ‘allNode’ was not declared in this scope
error: ‘name’ was not declared in this scope
```

Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Martin formatted the sourcecode for you but you should format it yourself so it makes more sense and you can easily spot errors in it when you have all the tabs and returns..

Answer (score 2):

In C++, you put the square brackets after the variable name, e.g.

```
Node allNode[10];
```

However, when dealing with dynamically-allocated arrays, use a pointer type:

```
Node *allNode = new Node[10];
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in the code. First `new Node[10]` returns the address of the first object, so your statement should be `Node* allNode = new Node[10];` . And I am not sure what is the meaning of this statement: `std::string allNode[i].curr`

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from this line:
`Node [] allNode=new Node[10];`
Which should be:
`Node* allNode=new Node[10];`

You're also not accessing the members of Node correctly.  See below for sample code:

```
int main
{
  Node* allNodes = new Node[10]; 

  for(i=0; i< 10; i++) 
  { 
    //create new node 
    allNodes[i] = new Node(); 

    allNodes[i]->el = "f"; 
    allNodes[i]->el2 = "g"; 
    allNodes[i]->curr = name + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(i); 

    std::cout << "Node name " << allNodes[i]->curr << std::endl;    
  }

  delete [] allNodes;
}
```